# Unmet dependencies while installing ROS Jade on Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: ros, ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have followed the installation procedure on the website. When I execute

```
sudo apt-get install ros-jade-desktop-full
```

I get the following error message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-jade-desktop-full : Depends: ros-jade-perception but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried installing the system dependencies as stated in the installation guide :

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-dev-lts-utopic mesa-common-dev-lts-utopic libxatracker-dev-lts-utopic libopenvg1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgbm-dev-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic



sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic
```

It still gives me the same error.

I have also tried to install the package separately

```
sudo apt-get install ros-jade-perception
```

Even this doesn't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229083/unmet-dependencies-while-installing-ros-jade-on-ubuntu-14.04.2/) by [Specas](https://answers.ros.org/users/26276/specas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try this :
sudo apt-get install tcl-vtk , then sudo apt-get install python-vtk and then sudo apt-get install ros-jade-desktop-full . It works for me.

---

Originally posted by [alphavanderson](https://answers.ros.org/users/26341/alphavanderson/) with karma: 46 on 2016-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Specas](https://answers.ros.org/users/26276/specas/) on 2016-04-01**:
This works!! Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [Klas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19207/klas/) on 2016-04-23**:
Thanks! This worked for me.

**Comment by [chambana](https://answers.ros.org/users/28837/chambana/) on 2016-12-18**:
Worked for me as well.